# Tag synonym suggestion: 'age-of-discovery' and 'age-of-exploration'

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

To the best of my knowledge, the Age of Discovery and the Age of Exploration refer to the same period of time. Should we make [age-of-exploration](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-exploration) a tag synonym of [age-of-discovery](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-discovery)?

I am of the opinion that we should make these legitimate tag synonyms, instead of just manually editing them, so that in the future the correct one shows up in new users' search suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I'm inclined to agree, as both seem like legit terms. What does everyone else think?

I do notice that [one of the (2) items](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/23118/were-there-any-chinese-expeditions-to-explore-the-world-if-not-why-not) under [age-of-exploration](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-exploration) technically doesn't fall under the tag description that [age-of-discovery](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-discovery) currently has, since it is about China. Still, I'd be OK with wedging it in there.